# Accessing out of declared boundary on members of structure or each dimension of multi-dimensional array

Tags: c, pointers

Can anyone give me an example for this statement. I read it somewhere, where it was mentioned that this kind of pointer usage is not recommended.

"Accessing out of declared boundary on members of structure or each dimension of multi-dimensional array."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This boils down to just *accessing outside the array bounds*:

```
int array[100];
int* pointer = array;
*(pointer + 100) = 0; // undefined behavior - the last valid index is 99
int value = *(pointer + 200); //undefined behavior just as well
```

any attempt to access elements outside of the array leads to undefined behavior which ,ight crash your program, corrupt data, whatever else. That's not what you call *not recommended*, that's what you call ***never do that***.

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue where that quote is from, but I can try to offer some explanation.

When you create an array (or `malloc`), the compiler (or libc) allocates space on the stack (or heap) to store that data. Other pieces of data may be stored around that data, and writing to indices of array that are greater than what was allocated can corrupt that data.

```
char x[5];
int y;
short z;

Raw memory: (just an example, likely to vary)
         00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
b0000000 xx xx xx xx xx -- -- -- yy yy yy yy zz zz -- --
```

where xx, yy, and zz, correspond to the x, y, and z variables accordingly, and -- is added padding. When you reference `x[4]`, that corresponds to address `x+sizeof(x[0])*4` (note not C syntax: normal arithmetic not pointer arithmetic) which is `b0000004`. When you write to `x[8]`, that corresponds to `b0000008` which is where `y` is located in this example. By writing to `x[8]`, you actually cause the value of `y` to change!

What could theoretically happen (but it is not defined what will happen):

```
char x[5];
int y;
short z;

y = 0x12345678;
x[8] = 0xad;
x[9] = 0xde;

printf("%#x\n", y);
/* 0x1234dead is printed ?!? */
```